# How do you state a regular expression in C# to skip a character, replace one with another and add a new character at a specific position?

Tags: c#, regex, subtitle

I have a C# program that takes as input a subtitle text file with contents like this:

```
1
00: 00: 07.966 -> 00: 00: 11.166
How's the sea?
- This is great. 

2
00: 00: 12.967 -> 00: 00: 15.766
It's really pretty.
```

What I want to do is basically correct it, so that it will skip any spaces, replace the `.` character with the `,` character and add another hyphen to the `->` string, so that it will become `-->`. For the previous example, the correct output would be:

```
1
00:00:07,966 --> 00:00:11,166
How's the sea?
- This is great. 

2
00:00:12,967 --> 00:00:15,766
It's really pretty.
```

So far, I've thought about iterating through each line and checking if it starts and ends with a digit, like so:

```
if (line.StartsWith("[0-9]") && line.EndsWith("[0-9]")) {
}
```

I don't know how to state the regular expression to do this, though.
Please take note that my input can have spaces anywhere at the subtitle timing line, not just after the `:` character, so the string can end up being as worse as this:

```
"^ 0 0 : 0 0 : 0 7 . 9 6 6 -> 0 0 : 0 0 : 1 1 . 1 6 6 $"
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you don't necessarily want a regular expression to do that, but you will need to work out how to normalize the input so that it always resembles the output. If only the spacing is inconsistent, this might work (and a simple Replace would do the job) - but if there's near-infinite variability, you need near-infinite flexibility... (see also: What if I add a regex? Aargh, now I have two (*thousand*!?) problems!) https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be a single regex that does everything, but I think that is actually an advantage and the logic is easy to follow and modify.

```
using var input = new StreamReader(inputPath);
using var output = new StreamWriter(outputPath);

// matches a timestamp line with a "->" and no alpha characters
var timestampRegex = new Regex(@"[^A-Za-z]*-\s*>[^A-Za-z]*");

string line;
while((line = input.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // if a timestamp line is found then it is modified
    if (timestampRegex.IsMatch(line))
    {
        line = Regex.Replace(line, @"\s", ""); // remove all whitespace
        line = line.Replace("->", " --> "); // update arrow style
    }

    output.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: I liked your solution as it's tackling the issue step by step. I also like that it works in Visual Studio. It looks like Ryszard's solution is not working in VS, maybe the regular expression is Unix oriented. It also solves the spacing problem, whereas his solution omits the issue.
Maybe it's my fault, because the question sounds like I'm asking specifically for a regular expression that does all the tasks at once.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it with the regular expression:

```cs
(?m)(?:\G(?!\A)|^(?=\d.*\d\r?$))(\d{2}:)[ \t](?:(\d+,\d+[ \t])(-)(>[ \t]))?
```

The replacement will be `$1$2$3$3$4`.

See [regex proof](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%5CG%28%3F!%5CA%29%7C%5E%28%3F%3D%5Cd.*%5Cd%5Cr%3F%24%29%29%28%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%29%5B%20%5Ct%5D%28%3F%3A%28%5Cd%2B%2C%5Cd%2B%5B%20%5Ct%5D%29%28-%29%28%3E%5B%20%5Ct%5D%29%29%3F&i=1%0D%0A00%3A%2000%3A%2007%2C966%20-%3E%2000%3A%2000%3A%2011%2C166%0D%0AHow%27s%20the%20sea%3F%0D%0A-%20This%20is%20great.%20%0D%0A%0D%0A2%0D%0A00%3A%2000%3A%2012%2C967%20-%3E%2000%3A%2000%3A%2015%2C766%0D%0AIt%27s%20really%20pretty.&r=%241%242%243%243%244&o=m).

**EXPLANATION**

```cs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?m)                     set flags for this block (with ^ and $
                           matching start and end of line) (case-
                           sensitive) (with . not matching \n)
                           (matching whitespace and # normally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \G                       where the last m//g left off
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \A                       the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of a "line"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \r?                      '\r' (carriage return) (optional
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                               a "line"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [ \t]                    any character of: ' ', '\t' (tab)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [ \t]                    any character of: ' ', '\t' (tab)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \4:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [ \t]                    any character of: ' ', '\t' (tab)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
```

[**C# code**](https://tio.run/##ZVJRT8IwEH7vrzgJia2OhU2FCIFpDFEfiImS@OA0KaOBJmVb1puOIL8djw0UpF3b3d33fXe5NrKNKMnUep1bHU/hZWFRzbts33JHqkD3WU1zI7NBkWbKWp3EtstYmo@NjiAy0loYFHKeGsWWDGhsQxYl0vGZ6AkMpY65KKMVZjMsZptUqURUWQw9uKnxoBPe8@AkvBXfHzzohRP3LMyCcFIXgoeTpb/qiDcI8Z2AZJ87tEpb8Ibg/epXBLXu/yQ2H1vUmCOVX2aqe3W/fkHz8his4zTHEuWxZrMD5Wo7160WNPqw83ie47Va7CH5OrWAMwVWyYA1YDTTFuibZkqiC4z5vyKeTyLtA5Erp00ij0gahDdmAdRlxIW7VxZdgCqe0k3tFpLt2Ttwu8PcoDY6Vn@0Qz7Jb/YexOqr8vBt552dpjjqBF046RKpJNNLSI2MFC8b5Bw0dY97R1KJUe5rplHxSmIbXrHVev0D):

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?:\G(?!\A)|^(?=\d.*\r?\d$))(\d{2}:)[ \t](?:(\d+,\d+[ \t])(-)(>[ \t]))?";
        string substitution = @"$1$2$3$3$4";
        string input = @"1
00: 00: 07,966 -> 00: 00: 11,166
How's the sea?
- This is great. 

2
00: 00: 12,967 -> 00: 00: 15,766
It's really pretty.";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
        Console.Write(result);
    }
}
```

**Results**:

```
1
00:00:07,966 --> 00:00:11,166
How's the sea?
- This is great. 

2
00:00:12,967 --> 00:00:15,766
It's really pretty.
```

Comment: That won't match the line OP writes at the end of the post.

Comment: @PoulBak That line looks like some regular expression than a line of input and does not start and end with a digit.